# Perform Operations on the same day using XTS in R

Tags: r, xts

I have what is hopefully a straightforward question. I have an `xts` object somewhat similar to the following:

```
                        | MarketPrice  |
----------------------------------------
2007-05-04 10:15:33.546 |   5.32       |
----------------------------------------
2007-05-04 10:16:42.100 |   5.31       |
----------------------------------------
2007-05-04 10:17:27.546 |   NA         |
----------------------------------------
2007-05-04 10:20:50.871 |   5.35       |
----------------------------------------
2007-05-04 10:21:38.652 |   5.37       |
```

Basically, I would like to find the `MarketPrice` index immediately before a time while also ommitting `NA` values. Let's say for instance we start at the time `2007-05-04 10:20:50.871` which has an index of 4 in the object. So this means that the Market Price immediately before this time is `5.31` which has an index of 2 in the object. In order to perform this task I have written up a function similar to the following:

```
 MPFunction <- function(t,df){

 ind <- t
 while(t>1){
     t=t-1
     if ( (index(df[t]) != index(df[ind])) && !(is.na(df[t,"MarketPrice"])))  {

    return(t)
   }
}
}
```

And this performs the task since the first condition in the IF statement checks to make sure the times in the index of the `xts` object are different and the second condition checks to make sure there is no `NA` value in the `MarketPrice` column.

However, I now run into an issue when I look at several days. Let's say I now have an `xts` object as follows:

```
                          | MarketPrice  |
  ----------------------------------------
  2007-05-03 16:59:58.921 |   5.32       |
  ----------------------------------------
  2007-05-04 10:12:27.546 |   NA         |
  ----------------------------------------
  2007-05-04 10:20:50.871 |   5.35       |
  ----------------------------------------
```

If I start at index 3 (i.e. at the time `2007-05-04 10:20:50.871`) then if I wish to find the first index before this time that doesn't have an `NA` value in the `MarketPrice` column, it will go to index 1 which is `2007-05-03 16:59:58.921`. The problem however is that this is on a different day, and I want to make sure that I only extract the index of `MarketPrice` values on the same day.

Basically, I was wondering if there is a quick modification I can make to my `MPFunction` above in the IF statement which will allow me to avoid finding the index of the MarketPrice from the previous day. Also, I do not wish to split the `xts` object up by day, since it would complicate things quite a bit if I did.

Now, I already have several idea on how to solve this (such as using the `strptime` function to check dates etc.) but these are all time-consuming methods, so I was hoping to find a method which is much much faster, so if anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you actually want to use `split.xts` (why is using split a complication?  It shouldn't be, even with large amounts of tick data in each day), and recombine the results:

```
zz=xts(order.by = as.POSIXct(c("2007-05-03 09:59:58.921", 
                               "2007-05-03 10:03:58.921",
                               "2007-05-03 12:03:58.921"
                  "2007-05-04 10:15:33.546",
                 "2007-05-04 10:16:42.100",
                 "2007-05-04 10:17:27.546",
                 "2007-05-04 10:20:50.871",
                 "2007-05-04 10:21:38.652")),
  x = c(3, 4, 9,  5.32, 5.31, NA, 5.35, 5.37), dimnames = list(NULL, "MarketPrice"))

> zz
#                      MarketPrice
# 2007-05-03 09:59:58        3.00
# 2007-05-03 10:03:58        4.00
# 2007-05-04 10:15:33        5.32
# 2007-05-04 10:16:42        5.31
# 2007-05-04 10:17:27          NA
# 2007-05-04 10:20:50        5.35
# 2007-05-04 10:21:38        5.37


MPFunction <- function(x, time_window = "T10/T10:16:40") {
  #last(x[time_window, which.i= TRUE])   # get the index?
  # last returns the last row in the group selected:
  #last(x[time_window,])
  u <- x[time_window, which.i = TRUE]

  if (length(u) > 0) {
    # Get index which is not an NA value:
    u.na <- which(is.na(x[time_window, "MarketPrice"]))
    u2 <- u[!u %in% u.na]
    if (length(u2) > 0) {
      v <- xts(order.by = end(x[last(u2)]), x = last(u2), dimnames = list(NULL, "index.i"))        
    } else {
      v <- NULL      
    }
  } else {
    v <- NULL
  }
  v
}

# use T0/ as the start of the time window in each day for getting the index value by default. You can change this though.
chosen_window = "T0/T10:17:29"

by_day <- lapply(split(zz, f = "day"), FUN = MPFunction, time_window = chosen_window)

rr <- do.call(rbind, by_day)

> rr
#                     index.i
# 2007-05-03 10:03:58       2
# 2007-05-04 10:16:42       2
```

If there are no values in a day in the `time_window` of interest, you will get `NULL` for that day, and nothing returned in the output (`rr`) for that day